# Java GUI Login from a text file

Tags: java, swing, text-files

i want to login from a text file called "ClientData.txt" which using 2nd (username) and third (password) line with "/" delimiter. but when i run it, it seems they cannot recognize it. please help here's my code :

```
File Login = new File ("ClientData.txt");
try{
    Scanner read = new Scanner (Login);
    read.useDelimiter("/");
    while (read.nextLine() !=null) {
        String user = read.next();
        read.next();
        if (jTextField1.getText().equals(user) && jPasswordField1.getText().equals(pass) && Clientbutton.isSelected()){
            new ClientMenu();
        }
    }
}   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the fact that new line characters are included in tokens with adjacent strings.

e.g.
File

```
John/Smith01
Walter/Isaacson01
```

Tokens: (1) John, (2) Smith01 **\n** Walter, (3) Isacson01

Solutions:

1. Change the delimiter `scanner.useDelimiter("(/|\\r\\n|\\n\\r|\\r|\\n)");` to include new line characters.
2. Use split instead of setting a delimiter:

   ```
   String line;
   while (scanner.hasNextLine() && !isBlank(line = scanner.nextLine())) {

        String[] accountData = line.split("/");
        String user = accountData[0];
        String password = accountData[1];
        System.out.println(user + ", " + password);
   }
   ```

   In this case `BufferedReader` class and `BufferedReader.readLine()` are preferable.

   Where `isBlank` is:

   ```
   private static boolean isBlank(String s) {
        return s == null || s.isEmpty();
   }
   ```